# database content not updated when accessing website from another device

Tags: java, mysql, database

I'm using Java EE + JSF + ¨Primefaces to create a basic crud application to learn creating web app using JEE, and I'm having a little problem.

I'm using NetBeans 8.2 + MySQL database to store my data.

Well, my **problem is the following**:

When I deploy the web app using GlassFish, everything is fine, and seems to work perfectly. Then, I decided to visit the website using my phone and I have tried to add a data (a user with its fields), the user **was added successfully** in the **database** (I checked in the terminal) and was shown in **my phone**.

When I **refreshed the page** in **my computer** that was showing the users, **the new added data was not there**. I had to re-deploy the project again so that I can see this new user.

I tried to do the other way around (add from my computer, then see then refresh the page in the phone), and still the same result, no new data until re-deployement.

I'm seeking help to this problem, so that when I add data from another device, it still can be shown, without redeploying.

p.s: (I know web sockets, and that's not what I'm trying to achieve).

Comment: if you data is saved in database, then how redeployment of application can show you data ?

Comment: I am not getting the point of your question.. database is just a mean to store data. 
But to answer your question, i use a query to get all the users.. so, if i refresh the page, basically, the query should work again and go to the database to get data (including the new ones)...
my question is excatly "why" i have to re-deploy to show the new data from another device.

Comment: That is my question as well why do you re-deploy your application ?? to fetch the data, you would be connecting to database right ? there is no relation here with application. If data is already saved in database, then why would you need to refresh you application where you haven't made any changes ???  why ???

Comment: I just tried to re-deploy it to see what happens. I have no idea why when i add data from a device (computer, or phone), the changes are shown in that device, and when i check the database from the terminal, the new data is inserted.. but, when i check the data from the other device, it's like nothing happened..

Answer (score 1):

Generated code is not all the time perfect and does not meet your requirement some times. Thus you have to change something in it.

- Try the following (If your code has been generated by Primeface CRUD generator pluggin)

You need to refresh() the entity from the entity manager and flush() it to ensure the entity you get has all the time the value stored in oder to get exactly what comes from the DB

look where i put *//pay attention* on this section

your **"AbstractFacade.java"** in your session bean package should look like this (you can copy/paste, and add the package name in the beginning if you want)

```
     import java.util.List;
     import java.util.Map;
     import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
     import javax.persistence.criteria.CriteriaBuilder;
     import javax.persistence.criteria.Expression;
     import javax.persistence.criteria.Predicate;
     import javax.persistence.criteria.Root;

    /**
     *
     * @author Daniel Rub <daniel.rubambura at danielrubambura@gmail.com>
     */
    public abstract class AbstractFacade<T> {

    private Class<T> entityClass;

    public AbstractFacade(Class<T> entityClass) {
        this.entityClass = entityClass;
    }

    protected abstract EntityManager getEntityManager();

    public void create(T entity) {
        getEntityManager().persist(entity);
    }

    public void edit(T entity) {
        getEntityManager().merge(entity);
    }


    public void remove(T entity) {
        getEntityManager().remove(getEntityManager().merge(entity));
    }

    public T find(Object id) {
        getEntityManager().flush();
        T result = getEntityManager().find(entityClass, id);
        //pay attention on this section
        getEntityManager().refresh(result);
        return result;
    }

    public List<T> findAll() {
        javax.persistence.criteria.CriteriaQuery cq = getEntityManager().getCriteriaBuilder().createQuery();
        cq.select(cq.from(entityClass));
        //pay attention on this section
        getEntityManager().flush();
        List resultList = getEntityManager().createQuery(cq).getResultList();
        for (Object object : resultList) {
            getEntityManager().refresh(object);
        }
        return resultList;
    }

    public List<T> findRange(int[] range) {
        javax.persistence.criteria.CriteriaQuery cq = getEntityManager().getCriteriaBuilder().createQuery();
        cq.select(cq.from(entityClass));
        javax.persistence.Query q = getEntityManager().createQuery(cq);
        q.setMaxResults(range[1] - range[0] + 1);
        q.setFirstResult(range[0]);
        //pay attention on this section
        getEntityManager().flush();
        List resultList = q.getResultList();
        for (Object result : resultList) {
            getEntityManager().refresh(result);
        }
        return resultList;
    }

    public int count() {
        javax.persistence.criteria.CriteriaQuery cq = getEntityManager().getCriteriaBuilder().createQuery();
        javax.persistence.criteria.Root<T> rt = cq.from(entityClass);
        cq.select(getEntityManager().getCriteriaBuilder().count(rt));
        javax.persistence.Query q = getEntityManager().createQuery(cq);
        //pay attention on this section
        getEntityManager().flush();
        return ((Long) q.getSingleResult()).intValue();
    }

    public List<T> findRange(int first, int pageSize, String sortField, String sortOrder, Map<String, Object> filters) {
        javax.persistence.criteria.CriteriaBuilder cb = getEntityManager().getCriteriaBuilder();
        javax.persistence.criteria.CriteriaQuery cq = cb.createQuery();
        javax.persistence.criteria.Root<T> entityRoot = cq.from(entityClass);
        cq.select(entityRoot);
        List<javax.persistence.criteria.Predicate> predicates = getPredicates(cb, entityRoot, filters);
        if (predicates.size() > 0) {
            cq.where(predicates.toArray(new javax.persistence.criteria.Predicate[]{}));
        }
        if (sortField != null && sortField.length() > 0) {
            if (entityRoot.get(sortField) != null) {
                if (sortOrder.startsWith("ASC")) {
                    cq.orderBy(cb.asc(entityRoot.get(sortField)));
                }
                if (sortOrder.startsWith("DESC")) {
                    cq.orderBy(cb.desc(entityRoot.get(sortField)));
                }
            }
        }
        javax.persistence.Query q = getEntityManager().createQuery(cq);
        q.setMaxResults(pageSize);
        q.setFirstResult(first);
        //pay attention on this section
        getEntityManager().flush();
        List resultList = q.getResultList();
        for (Object result : resultList) {
            getEntityManager().refresh(result);
        }
        return resultList;
    }

    public List<T> findRange(int first, int pageSize, Map<String, String> sortFields, Map<String, Object> filters) {
        javax.persistence.criteria.CriteriaBuilder cb = getEntityManager().getCriteriaBuilder();
        javax.persistence.criteria.CriteriaQuery cq = cb.createQuery();
        javax.persistence.criteria.Root<T> entityRoot = cq.from(entityClass);
        cq.select(entityRoot);
        List<javax.persistence.criteria.Predicate> predicates = getPredicates(cb, entityRoot, filters);
        if (predicates.size() > 0) {
            cq.where(predicates.toArray(new javax.persistence.criteria.Predicate[]{}));
        }
        if (sortFields != null && !sortFields.isEmpty()) {
            for (String sortField : sortFields.keySet()) {
                if (entityRoot.get(sortField) != null) {
                    String sortOrder = sortFields.get(sortField);
                    if (sortOrder.startsWith("ASC")) {
                        cq.orderBy(cb.asc(entityRoot.get(sortField)));
                    }
                    if (sortOrder.startsWith("DESC")) {
                        cq.orderBy(cb.desc(entityRoot.get(sortField)));
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        javax.persistence.Query q = getEntityManager().createQuery(cq);
        q.setMaxResults(pageSize);
        q.setFirstResult(first);
        //pay attention on this section
        getEntityManager().flush();
        List resultList = q.getResultList();
        for (Object result : resultList) {
            getEntityManager().refresh(result);
        }
        return resultList;
    }

    public int count(Map<String, Object> filters) {
        javax.persistence.criteria.CriteriaBuilder cb = getEntityManager().getCriteriaBuilder();
        javax.persistence.criteria.CriteriaQuery cq = cb.createQuery();
        javax.persistence.criteria.Root<T> entityRoot = cq.from(entityClass);
        cq.select(cb.count(entityRoot));
        List<javax.persistence.criteria.Predicate> predicates = getPredicates(cb, entityRoot, filters);
        if (predicates.size() > 0) {
            cq.where(predicates.toArray(new javax.persistence.criteria.Predicate[]{}));
        }
        getEntityManager().flush();
        javax.persistence.Query q = getEntityManager().createQuery(cq);
        return ((Long) q.getSingleResult()).intValue();
    }

    private List<Predicate> getPredicates(CriteriaBuilder cb, Root<T> entityRoot, Map<String, Object> filters) {
        javax.persistence.metamodel.Metamodel entityModel = this.getEntityManager().getMetamodel();
        javax.persistence.metamodel.ManagedType<T> entityType = entityModel.managedType(entityClass);
        java.util.Set<javax.persistence.metamodel.EmbeddableType<?>> embeddables = entityModel.getEmbeddables();
        String fieldTypeName = null;
        // Add predicates (WHERE clauses) based on filters map
        List<javax.persistence.criteria.Predicate> predicates = new java.util.ArrayList<>();
        for (String s : filters.keySet()) {
            javax.persistence.criteria.Path<Object> pkFieldPath = null;
            if (s.contains(".")) {
                String embeddedIdField = s.split("\\.")[0];
                String embeddedIdMember = s.split("\\.")[1];
                pkFieldPath = entityRoot.get(embeddedIdField).get(embeddedIdMember);
                javax.persistence.metamodel.EmbeddableType<?> embeddableType = entityModel.embeddable(entityType.getAttribute(embeddedIdField).getJavaType());
                fieldTypeName = embeddableType.getAttribute(embeddedIdMember).getJavaType().getName();
            } else {
                pkFieldPath = entityRoot.get(s);
                fieldTypeName = entityType.getAttribute(s).getJavaType().getName();
            }
            if (pkFieldPath != null && fieldTypeName != null) {
                if (fieldTypeName.contains("String")) {
                    predicates.add(cb.like((javax.persistence.criteria.Expression) pkFieldPath, filters.get(s) + "%"));
                } else {
                    javax.persistence.criteria.Expression<?> filterExpression = getCastExpression((String) filters.get(s), fieldTypeName, cb);
                    if (filterExpression != null) {
                        predicates.add(cb.equal((javax.persistence.criteria.Expression<?>) pkFieldPath, filterExpression));
                    } else {
                        predicates.add(cb.equal((javax.persistence.criteria.Expression<?>) pkFieldPath, filters.get(s)));
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return predicates;
    }

    private Expression<?> getCastExpression(String searchValue, String typeName, CriteriaBuilder cb) {
        javax.persistence.criteria.Expression<?> expression = null;
        switch (typeName) {
            case "short":
                expression = cb.literal(Short.parseShort(searchValue));
                break;
            case "byte":
                expression = cb.literal(Byte.parseByte(searchValue));
                break;
            case "int":
                expression = cb.literal(Integer.parseInt(searchValue));
                break;
            case "long":
                expression = cb.literal(Long.parseLong(searchValue));
                break;
            case "float":
                expression = cb.literal(Float.parseFloat(searchValue));
                break;
            case "double":
                expression = cb.literal(Double.parseDouble(searchValue));
                break;
            case "boolean":
                expression = cb.literal(Boolean.parseBoolean(searchValue));
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
        return expression;
    }

}
```

- if your code has been generated by the default netbeans crud generator

  your **"AbstractFacade.java"** should look the following :
  look where i put //pay attention on this section

  ```
  import java.util.List;
  import javax.persistence.EntityManager;

  /**
   *
   * @author daniel
   */
  public abstract class AbstractFacade<T> {

  private Class<T> entityClass;

  public AbstractFacade(Class<T> entityClass) {
      this.entityClass = entityClass;
  }

  protected abstract EntityManager getEntityManager();

  public void create(T entity) {
      getEntityManager().persist(entity);
  }

  public void edit(T entity) {
      getEntityManager().merge(entity);
  }

  public void remove(T entity) {
      getEntityManager().remove(getEntityManager().merge(entity));
  }

  public T find(Object id) {
      //pay attention on this section
      getEntityManager().flush();
      T item = getEntityManager().find(entityClass, id);
      getEntityManager().refresh(item);
      return item;

  }

  public List<T> findAll() {
      javax.persistence.criteria.CriteriaQuery cq = getEntityManager().getCriteriaBuilder().createQuery();
      //pay attention on this section
      getEntityManager().flush();
      cq.select(cq.from(entityClass));
      List resultList = getEntityManager().createQuery(cq).getResultList();
      for (Object object : resultList) {
          getEntityManager().refresh(object);
      }
      return resultList;

  }

  public List<T> findRange(int[] range) {
      javax.persistence.criteria.CriteriaQuery cq = getEntityManager().getCriteriaBuilder().createQuery();
      //pay attention on this section
      getEntityManager().flush();
      cq.select(cq.from(entityClass));
      javax.persistence.Query q = getEntityManager().createQuery(cq);
      q.setMaxResults(range[1] - range[0] + 1);
      q.setFirstResult(range[0]);
      List resultList = q.getResultList();
      for (Object object : resultList) {
          getEntityManager().refresh(object);
      }
      return resultList;
  }

  public int count() {
      javax.persistence.criteria.CriteriaQuery cq = getEntityManager().getCriteriaBuilder().createQuery();
      javax.persistence.criteria.Root<T> rt = cq.from(entityClass);
      cq.select(getEntityManager().getCriteriaBuilder().count(rt));
      javax.persistence.Query q = getEntityManager().createQuery(cq);
      return ((Long) q.getSingleResult()).intValue();
  }
  ```

  }

Comment: You don't have to answer like that on such questions, just give a link when the answer might be found on a web site.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. The above code is not from a website. It's my own way of fixing the problem when i got the same problem.